# how to add monthly count average

Tags: sql

I am looking for all counts when dimsyermid=-1 and also make a new column calculate avg per month. Below are my current queries and result, I don't know how to add a new column calculate avg per month.
query:

```
select DimSystemID, EligibleYM, count(*)
from  dbo.table1  
where DimSystemID=-1
group by DimSystemID, EligibleYM 
order by 2 desc, 1
```

Result table

```
DimSystemID EligibleYM  (No column name)
-1             202001   75
-1             201912   70
-1             201911   67
-1             201910   67
-1            201909    59
```

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  (2) What results do you want?  (3) What do YOU mean by "calculate avg per month"?  I see only one value per month, and that is its own average.

Comment: 1) SQL, 2). I want to know how many accounts when Dimsysyermid=-1 in a year range, so the date should be a current month back 11 months. for example, sep 19 monthly avg, that is October 18- Sep 19. if total -1 =1200, then Sep 19 avg is 1200/12=10. I want to see that for each month.

Comment: never mind, I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack. Making the assumption that you have some values that you want to average in your data set but not shown in your question, in MS SQL, you would just create another computed column that does the math:

```
select DimSystemID, EligibleYM, count(*), [new computed column here as AVG]
from  dbo.table1  
where DimSystemID=-1
group by DimSystemID, EligibleYM 
order by 2 desc, 1
```

with an example:

```
select DimSystemID, EligibleYM, count(*), AVG(MONTH DATA HERE)
```

An example (anonymized) of your data would help.

[MSSQL AVG Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I want to know how many accounts when Dimsysyermid=-1 in a year range, so the date should be a current month back 11 months. for example, sep 19 monthly avg, that is October 18- Sep 19. if total -1 =1200, then Sep 19 avg is 1200/12=10. I want to see that for each month.